# Anyone use a custom fuel line repair kit from eBay?

Tags: fuel-system, leak, fuel-injection, fuel-line

My fuel line has started leaking and needs to be replaced.

I saw a YouTube video of someone who used [this 96-00 Civic 2dr Coupe Replacement Stainless Steel Fuel Feed Line & Rubber Return from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/141796374057) to replace his.

Apparently it's cut to length and has the same oem style fittings for the main line making it all plug and play

- How well does it work long term?
- Any feedback from anyone who may have used it or something similar?

Comment: You may want to edit the question it sounds like shopping advice.

Answer (score 1):

Stainless braided hose is just rubber hose with a stainless steel outer weave. It's usually meant for higher pressure applications to prevent flexing of the hose. In this case it seems to be just for appearances sake. I wouldn't expect the line to last any longer than a normal hose. To be honest you could probably just run rubber fuel hose from front to back.

Note that, that braided line uses AN fittings and you need special wrenches when working with AN fittings as to not round off the fitting.

Comment: What are AN fittings? How long does a rubber hose generally last?

Comment: @ohmmy check out the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN_thread. As to how long the rubber hoses will last, it depends on the area you live in. You can expect the hoses to last years.

Comment: I live on New England that's why my hard lines rusted out. As long as the rubber lasts a few years I think it'd be worth it. Would there be any risk installing that following a different route than original lines? They seem thicker and probably wouldn't fit where old lines are

Comment: @ohmmy just be careful in how they're routed. You don't want the lines to pinch or anything like that. Other than that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the line itself is leaking, most times a leak is at a connection point, they just might need to be tightened. If the line was leaking from rusting, I doubt the motor would get enough fuel to run and the fuel would be all on the ground.

As for the steel-braided hose, the braiding is for protection and that type of hose is excellent for fuel lines, I use it on my race car. And you stated that it comes with OEM style fittings so you should not need any adapters, and as for the wrenching, they are standard sizes so special wrenches are not necessary, just don't over tighten them, THAT is what the AN wrenches are for.

The biggest issue I see with the braided hose is that will be thicker than the old line and you may not able to route it the same as the original. When routing it, keep it away from heat such as the exhaust system and don't worry, you will not be able to pinch it, the steel braiding will prevent that from happening.